# I want to make a program where an input from the user is separated into 3 circular linked lists. But I am facing return value 3221225725 error

Tags: c++, linked-list, runtime-error, circular-list

A Bank manager want to segregate different Currency notes in to 3 different baskets. Initially, all the  currencies  are  in  one  Basket  and  the  currencies  are  USD,  INR  and    EUR.  Now,  you  are supposed  to  write  a  program  that  can  segregate  the  currencies  to  3  different  buckets.  While, segregation,  make  sure  to  have  a  track  of  the  overall  sum  of  the  currencies  in  terms  of  INR  for each basket.

**Program Requirements:**
1.First get the input from the user for the overall Basket. [Even numbers are mapped as USD,  Odd  numbers  are  mapped  as  INR  and  Prime  numbers  are  mapped  as  EUR,  if there is an intersection, you are free to select any one of them]

2.After receiving the elements of the Basket, try a function to segregate the currencies

3.While adding the currency to its corresponding basket, ensure to calculate the overall sum.

4.Whenever,  the  bank  manager  wants  to  see  the  basket,  you  should  display  all  the baskets and its corresponding SUM, MEAN, MEDIAN and MODE.

5.Also,  there  should  be  a  provision  to  remove  required  amount  of  currency  in  each basket.  [While  removal,  you  need  to  enter  the  amount  of  removal  in  INR  and  its corresponding value should be removed from the respective basket]

**NOTE:** Use the value, USD = 73 INR and EUR = 86.5 INR

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int prime(int n);

struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *next;
}*last;

class circular_llist
{
    public:
        void insert(int value);
        void delete_element(int value);
        void display_list();
        circular_llist()
        {
            last = NULL;
        }
};

int main()
{
    int element, choice, ch;
    int arr[100], i, n, x;
    int sum_usd=0, sum_inr=0, sum_eur=0;
    int c_usd=0, c_inr=0, c_eur=0;
    int arr_usd[n], arr_inr[n], arr_eur[n];
    
    
    cout << "Enter the total number of elements" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter the elements:" << endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cin >> x;
        arr[i]=x;
    }
    
    circular_llist usd;
    circular_llist inr;
    circular_llist eur;
    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        if(prime(arr[i])==1) {
            eur.insert(arr[i]);
            sum_eur+=arr[i];
            c_eur++;
        }
        else if(arr[i]%2==0) {
            usd.insert(arr[i]);
            sum_usd+=arr[i];
            c_usd++;
        } else {
            inr.insert(arr[i]);
            sum_inr+=arr[i];
            c_inr++;
        }
    }
    
    do{
        cout << "1.Delete Element" << endl;
        cout << "2.Display elements" << endl;
        cout << "3.Show mathematical figures" << endl;
        cout << "4.Quit" << endl;
        cin >> ch;
        
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1:
                cout << "From which basket do you want to delete?" << endl;
                cout << "1.USD" << endl << "2.INR" << endl << "3.EUR" << endl;
                cin >> choice;
                switch(choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        if (last == NULL)
                        {
                            cout<<"List is empty, nothing to delete"<<endl;
                            break;
                        }
                        cout<<"Enter the element for deletion: ";
                        cin>>element;
                        usd.delete_element(element);
                        cout<<endl;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if (last == NULL)
                        {
                            cout<<"List is empty, nothing to delete"<<endl;
                            break;
                        }
                        cout<<"Enter the element for deletion: ";
                        cin>>element;
                        inr.delete_element(element);
                        cout<<endl;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        if (last == NULL)
                        {
                            cout<<"List is empty, nothing to delete"<<endl;
                            break;
                        }
                        cout<<"Enter the element for deletion: ";
                        cin>>element;
                        eur.delete_element(element);
                        cout<<endl;
                        break;
                }
            case 2:
                cout << "From whick basket do you want to diplay thye elements?" << endl;
                cout << "1.USD" << endl << "2.INR" << endl << "3.EUR" << endl;
                cin >> choice;
                switch(choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        usd.display_list();
                        cout << endl;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        inr.display_list();
                        cout << endl;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        eur.display_list();
                        cout << endl;
                        break;
                }
            case 3:
                cout << "For which basket do you want tp show the mathematical figures?" << endl;
                cout << "1.USD" << endl << "2.INR" << endl << "3.EUR" << endl;
                cin >> choice;
                switch(choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        cout << "Sum = " << sum_usd << endl;
                        cout << "Mean = " << endl;
                    case 2:
                        cout << "Sum = " << sum_inr << endl;
                    case 3:
                        cout << "Sum = " << sum_eur << endl;
                }
            case 4:
                cout << "EXIT" << endl;
                break;
            default :
                cout << "Choose a valid option" << endl;
                break;
        }
    }while(ch!=4);
    
    return 0;
}

/*
 * Create Circular Link List
 */
void circular_llist::insert(int value)
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp = new(struct node);
    temp->info = value;
    if (last == NULL)
    {
        last = temp;
        temp->next = last;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->next = last->next;
        last->next = temp;
        last = temp;
    }
}

/*
 * Deletion of element from the list
 */
void circular_llist::delete_element(int value)
{
    struct node *temp, *s;
    s = last->next;
      /* If List has only one element*/
    if (last->next == last && last->info == value)  
    {
        temp = last;
        last = NULL;
        free(temp);
        return;
    }
    if (s->info == value)  /*First Element Deletion*/
    {
        temp = s;
        last->next = s->next;
        free(temp);
        return;
    }
    while (s->next != last)
    {
        /*Deletion of Element in between*/
        if (s->next->info == value)    
        {
            temp = s->next;
            s->next = temp->next;
            free(temp);
            cout<<"Element "<<value;
            cout<<" deleted from the list"<<endl;
            return;
        }
        s = s->next;
    }
    /*Deletion of last element*/
    if (s->next->info == value)    
    {
        temp = s->next;
        s->next = last->next;
        free(temp);     
        last = s;
        return;
    }
    cout<<"Element "<<value<<" not found in the list"<<endl;
}

 
/*
 * Display Circular Link List 
 */
void circular_llist::display_list()
{
    struct node *s;
    if (last == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"List is empty, nothing to display"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    s = last->next;
    cout<<"Circular Link List: "<<endl;
    while (s != last)
    {
        cout<<s->info<<"->";
        s = s->next;
    }
    cout<<s->info<<endl;
}

/*
*Check in the element is prime or not
 */
int prime(int n) {
    int i;
    int a;
    
    for(i=2;i<n;i++){
        if(n%i==0) {
            a = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this: `int arr_usd[n], arr_inr[n], arr_eur[n];`

Into this: `int arr_usd[20], arr_inr[20], arr_eur[20];`

or any other number other than 20. It shows an error as n value hasn't been initialised yet.

Comment: in the main function

Answer (score 0):

**Done completely using LinkedList in C**

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    float data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node *EUR=NULL;
struct Node *USD=NULL;
struct Node *INR=NULL;

void sort(struct Node **h){
    struct Node* node1;
    struct Node* node2;
    int temp;
    for(node1=*h;node1!=NULL;node1=node1->next){
        for(node2=node1->next;node2!=NULL;node2=node2->next){
            if(node1->data>node2->data){
                temp = node1->data;
                node1->data = node2->data;
                node2->data = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void add(float val,struct Node **h){
    struct Node *temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data = val;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if(*h==NULL){
        *h = temp;
        return;
    }

    struct Node *node = *h;
    while(node->next!=NULL){
        node = node->next;
    }

    node->next = temp;
}

void delete(struct Node** h, float amt){
    struct Node *node = *h;
    if(*h!=NULL){
        if(node->data==amt){
            *h = node->next;
        }else{
            int flag=0;
            while(node->next!=NULL){
                if(node->next->data==amt){
                    node->next = node->next->next;
                    flag=1;
                    printf("[*]Amount removed\n");
                    break;
                }
                node = node->next;
            }
            if(!flag){
                printf("[*]Amount not in Basket!!!\n");
            }
        }
    }else{
        printf("[*]Failed\tZero Balance\n");
    }
}

float sum(struct Node** h){
    if(*h==NULL)
        return 0;
    float s=0;
    struct Node *node = *h;
    while(node!=NULL){
        s += node->data;
        node = node->next;
    }
    return s;
}

float mean(struct Node** h){
    if(*h==NULL)
        return 0;
    int l=0;
    float m,s=0;
    struct Node *node = *h;
    while(node!=NULL){
        l++;
        s += node->data;
        node = node->next;
    }

    m =s/l;
    return m;
}

float median(struct Node** h){

    if(*h==NULL)
        return -1;

    float med;
    struct Node* f_node = *h;
    struct Node* p_node = *h;
    struct Node* s_node = *h;

    while(f_node!=NULL && f_node->next!=NULL){
        f_node = f_node->next->next;
        p_node = s_node;
        s_node = s_node->next;
    }
    if(f_node!=NULL){//odd
        med = s_node->data;
    }else{
        med = (p_node->data+s_node->data)/2;
    }
    return med;
}

int mode(struct Node **h){
    if(*h==NULL)
        return 0;

    int max_value=0;
    int count,max_count = 0;

    struct Node *node = *h;
    while (node!=NULL){
        count = 0;
        struct Node *node2 = node->next;
        while(node2!=NULL){
            if(node->data==node2->data)
                count++;
            node2 = node2->next;
        }
        if(count>max_count){
            max_value = node->data;
            max_count = count;
        }
        node = node->next;
    }
    if(max_count==0)
        return 0;
    return max_value;
}

void print(struct Node** h,char *m){
    printf("printing %s>>>\n",m);
    if(*h==NULL){
        printf("[*]No bills\n");
        return;
    }
    struct Node* node = *h;
    while(node->next!=NULL){
        printf("%.2f->",node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("%.2f\n",node->data);
    printf("[*]SUM: %.2f\n",sum(h));
    printf("[*]MEAN: %.2f\n",mean(h));
    printf("[*]MEDIAN: %.2f\n",median(h));
    printf("[*]MODE: %d\n",mode(h));
}

int even(int n){
    if(n%2==0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int prime(int n){
    for(int i=2;i<=n/2;i++){
        if(n%i==0){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
int main(){

    int n;
    int num;
    printf("Enter total no of bills: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    float eur = 86.5f;
    float usd = 73.0f;
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Enter bill %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&num);
        if(prime(num))
            add(eur*num,&EUR);
        else if(even(num))
            add(usd*num,&USD);
        else
            add((float)num,&INR);
    }
    sort(&EUR);
    sort(&USD);
    sort(&INR);

    int ch1,ch2,br=0;
    float amt;
    while(1){
        printf("1.Display Baskets\n2.Delete Amount\n3.Quit\nEnter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d",&ch1);

        switch(ch1){
            case 1:
                print(&EUR,"EURO");
                print(&USD,"USD");
                print(&INR,"INR");
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("Enter amount to be deleted: ");
                scanf("%f",&amt);
                printf("Delete From>>>\n1.EUR\t2.USD\t3.INR");
                scanf("%d",&ch2);
                
                switch(ch2){
                    case 1:
                        delete(&EUR,amt);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        delete(&USD,amt);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        delete(&INR,amt);
                        break;
                    default:
                        printf("[*]Wrong Input\n");
                        break;
                }
                break;

            default:
                br = 1;
                break;
        }
        if(br)
            break;
    }
}```
````